# Mocking Twilio Client from twilio-node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocking, twilio, twilio-api

I currently use The [Twilio Node Helper Library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/twilio) to do various API calls whether it may be to create assistants/services, list them, remove them and various other things when it comes to uploading tasks, samples, fields to create a chatbot on Twilio Autopilot.

An example of one some of these functions include:

```
async function createAssistant(name, client){
    var assistantUid = ""
    await client.autopilot.assistants
                .create({
                    friendlyName: name,
                    uniqueName: name
                    })
                .then(assistant => assistantUid = assistant.sid);
    return assistantUid 
}

 async function getAccount(client){
    var valid = true
    try {
      await client.api.accounts.list()
    } catch (e) {
      valid = false
    }

    return valid
  }


async function connectToTwilio(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken) {
  try{
    var client = twilio(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);
  } catch (e){
    throw new TwilioRequestError(e)
  }

  var valid = await getAccount(client)
  if(valid && client._httpClient.lastResponse.statusCode === 200){
    return client
  } else{
    throw new Error("Invalid Twilio Credentials")
  }
  
}
```

where client is the client object returned from require("twilio")(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken).

I was wondering what would the best way of mocking this API to allow me to emulate creating assistants, returning their uniqueNames etc..

I was wondering that I may just define some class like

```
class TwilioTestClient{

   constructor(sid, token){
        this.sid = sid
        this.token = token
        this.assistants = TwilioAssistant()
        this.services = TwilioServices()
   }
}
```

Where TwilioAssitant and TwilioServices will be additional classes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with mocking Twilio for a long time.  In fact I previously architected my application such that I could mock a wrapper around the Twilio Node Helper just to avoid mocking the actual library.  But recent changes to the architecture meant that was no longer an option.  This morning I finally got a mock of the Twilio Node Helper Library working.  I'm not familiar with the portions of the Twilio library you are using, but I'm hopeful the example here will help you.

We have a function to check if a phone number is mobile, call it `isMobile.js`.

```
const Twilio = require("twilio");

const isMobile = async (num) => {
    const TwilioClient = new Twilio(process.env.TWILIO_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);

    try {
        const twilioResponse = await TwilioClient.lookups.v1
            .phoneNumbers(num)
            .fetch({ type: "carrier", mobile_country_code: "carrier" });

        const { carrier: { type } = {} } = twilioResponse;
        return type === "mobile";
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
};

module.exports = isMobile;
```

Then build a mock for Twilio in `__mocks__/twilio.js`

```
const mockLookupClient = {
    v1: { phoneNumbers: () => ({ fetch: jest.fn(() => {}) }) }
};

module.exports = class Twilio {
    constructor(sid, token) {
        this.lookups = mockLookupClient;
    }
};
```

In the test file `isMobile.test.js`

```
jest.mock("twilio");

const Twilio = require("twilio");

const isMobile = require("./isMobile");

const mockFetch = jest.fn();
const mockPhoneNumbers = jest.fn(() => ({
    fetch: mockFetch
}));

describe("isMobile", () => {
    const TwilioClient = new Twilio(process.env.TWILIO_SID, process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN);
    const lookupClient = TwilioClient.lookups.v1;
    lookupClient.phoneNumbers = mockPhoneNumbers;

    beforeEach(() => {
        mockFetch.mockReset();
    });

    test("is a function", () => {
        expect(typeof isMobile).toBe("function");
    });

    test("returns true for valid mobile number", async () => {
        const validMobile = "+14037007492";

        mockFetch.mockReturnValueOnce({
            carrier: { type: "mobile", mobile_country_code: 302 }, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
            phoneNumber: validMobile
        });
        expect(await isMobile(validMobile)).toBe(true);
    });

    test("returns false for non-mobile number", async () => {
        const invalidMobile = "+14035470770";

        mockFetch.mockReturnValueOnce({
            carrier: { type: "not-mobile", mobile_country_code: null }, // eslint-disable-line camelcase
            phoneNumber: invalidMobile
        });

        expect(await isMobile(invalidMobile)).toBe(false);
    });
});
```